# How to change color of a button first Click and bringing back previous color on second click in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, onclick

This is code snippet of what I am doing. It is not working. What am I doing wrong?

I am using a listview. 
I have used Viewholder. 
I have initiaally assigned color_green in my XML.
I want that on each click color changes to red and when again clicked it changes back to green.

This is my getView

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowlist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            holder.button2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            holder.img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Student student = getItem(position);

        holder.name.setText(student.getName());
        holder.button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //  int x = (Integer) holder.button1.getTag(position);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked on "+position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

This following functionality I want to be implemented in my onClickListener of button1

```
        final Button button1 = (Button) itemView.getTag(R.id.button1);
        final int currentPostion1 = position;
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button1.getBackground();
            int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Log.d("msg", "Inside onClick");
                if(colorId==R.color.color_green)
                {
                    Log.d("msg", "Inside onClick1 if"); 
                    button1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.color_red);
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " "+currentPostion1+" ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //flag=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("msg", "Inside onClick else");
                    button1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.color_green);
                    //                      button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    //                      flag=1;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: use CheckBox or something which has 2 states(checked,unchecked)...and set different drawable for each state

Comment: I want to do without using checkbox.

Comment: Tag a value with the view so that you can recognize its color in onClick...then compare the tagged value, set color accordingly and update tagged value.

Comment: The identifier for a color Resource (e.g., `R.color.color_green`) does map to an `int`. However, that is not the same thing as the `int` value for a Color (e.g., `buttonColor.getColor()`). You cannot logically compare the two.

Comment: Then how to compare color resource with value of color.

Comment: In your Adapter, e.g., `getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_green)` will return the `int` value for the Color. You'll need to change your `setBackgroundColor()` calls, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button1.getBackground();
        int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Log.d("msg", "Inside onClick");
            if(colorId==R.color.color_green)
            {
                Log.d("msg", "Inside onClick1 if"); 
                button1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " "+currentPostion1+" ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //flag=0;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("msg", "Inside onClick else");
                button1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                //                      flag=1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use boolean to achieve that,

```
//global variable
boolean click=true;

if(click){
//first click
//change color
click = false;
}else{
//second click
//change color
click = true;
}
```